# how solve Recursive Queries error in intodns web site?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, query, recursive

Please see the below link :
[intoDNS Web Site](http://www.intodns.com/darmanlive.com)
How can I solve Recursive Queries error!
the entire error is below :

> **Recursive Queries**  I could use the nameservers listed below to
>   performe recursive queries. It may be that I am wrong but the chances
>   of that are low. You should not have nameservers that allow recursive
>   queries as this will allow almost anyone to use your nameservers and
>   can cause problems. Problem record(s) are:
>   188.138.85.86

Also I have one IP address -> what can I do about ns2 -> are those error about ns2 important for google bots or SEO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Windows Server and its DNS software - I do UNIX stuff.

That said, what you should be looking for is some form of ACL which tells the server which IP addresses are allowed to send recursive queries to your server - ideally none!

This [Microsoft page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771738.aspx) appears to be relevant - it tells you how to disable recursion completely.

For `ns2` you have two errors:

1. it doesn't respond (or exist?) at all!
2. it isn't listed in the copy of the zone file hosted on `ns1`

Answer (score 0):

*I know it's late to answer but I had same question googled for my Linux server and directed here so I'm sharing the solution I found for recursive queries problem:*

- find `options{} section in /etc/named.conf` file and limit `allow-query` value to `{localhost;}` rather than `{any;}`.
- add allow query for each zone individually in `named.conf` file:

  ```
  zone "yourdomain.tld" {
      type master;
      file "/var/named/yourdomain.tld.hosts";
      allow-query     { any; };
  };
  ```